# shiny leaflet mouseover popup

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I would like to build a shiny app that has a popup show up when the mouse goes over a shape/circle rather than the standard click

in particular i am trying to get the popup show as the mouse hovers over...and it disappears as the mouse moves away from it.

This page (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) would suggest i need to have something like an `observeEvent({input$mymap_shape_mouseover},{showPopup()})`

but not sure where to enter it or how to use it, so any help would be much appreciated.

Below is a simple random example...

```
    library(shiny)
    library(leaflet)
    library(data.table)


    uu <-  data.table(row_num=seq(100),
                    Latitude=c(52+cumsum(runif(100,-0.001,0.001))),
                    Longitude=c(1+cumsum(runif(100,-0.001,0.001)))
    )





  ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("mymap")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        addCircles(lng=uu$Longitude,
                   lat=uu$Latitude,
                   radius=2)
    })

    # Show a popup at the given location
    show_popup_on_mouseover <- function(id, lat, lng) {
      selected_point <- uu[row_num == id,]
      content <- as.character(selected_point$row_num)
      leafletProxy("mymap") %>% 
        addPopups(lng, lat, content)
    }


    # When circle is hovered over...show a popup
    observe({
      leafletProxy("mymap") %>% clearPopups()
      event <- input$mymap_shape_mouseover
      print(event)
      if (is.null(event)){
        return()
      } else {
        isolate({
          show_popup_on_mouseover(event$id, event$lat, event$lng)
        })
      }
    })


  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is quite a challenge. And it cannot be fully resolved, I guess.

Here is the thing: If you want to use the mouse events on Shiny side to create and delete some popups, you cannot rely on the leaflet events you get.

In more detail: You were right to trigger the Popup on `input$mymap_shape_mouseover`. In your example, you also used the `clearPopups` function each time a new popup is created. This can be avoided by setting a shared `layerId`, like I use in my almost working example below, to ensure having only one popup open. Other than that, my example is logically mostly the same.

At first I thought one could bind the `clearPopup` function to the `mouseout` event on your circles, but there is a problem. Whenever you add a popup, the popup container will be directly under your cursor, and thus, `mouseout` fires, even if the curser still is above the marker/circle. So this results in flashing popups, being generated and immediately deleted, resulting in the mouse being on the circle again, thus rendering the popup again, and so on.

A possible fix would have been to take the `input$mymap_popup_mouseover` into account, but unfortunately, there is a bug in the `leaflet` package and the popup mouse events cannot be accessed. I added a comment to an issue on [Github](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/190) and Joe Chang immediately promised to look into this.

Closest one can get:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)

uu <-  data.table(
  row_num=seq(100),
  Latitude=c(52+cumsum(runif(100,-0.001,0.001))),
  Longitude=c(1+cumsum(runif(100,-0.001,0.001)))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircles(lng = uu$Longitude, lat = uu$Latitude, radius = 2, layerId = uu$row_num)
  })

  # When circle is hovered over...show a popup
  observeEvent(input$mymap_shape_mouseover$id, {
    pointId <- input$mymap_shape_mouseover$id

    lat = uu[uu$row_num == pointId, Latitude]
    lng = uu[uu$row_num == pointId, Longitude]
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>% addPopups(lat = lat, lng = lng, as.character(pointId), layerId = "hoverPopup")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT: Cheap fix.**

Another possibility is the workaround below. If you can live with popups being  slightly offset, you can avoid the `mouseover/mouseout` problem. When rendering the popup above the circle, such that the popup container is fully outside of the circle, everything works fine. The offset calculation is purely by trial.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)

uu <-  data.table(
  row_num=seq(100),
  Latitude=c(52+cumsum(runif(100,-0.001,0.001))),
  Longitude=c(1+cumsum(runif(100,-0.001,0.001)))
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  radius = 3

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircles(lng = uu$Longitude, lat = uu$Latitude, radius = radius, layerId = uu$row_num)
  })

  observeEvent(input$mymap_shape_mouseout$id, {
    leafletProxy("mymap") %>% clearPopups()
  })

  # When circle is hovered over...show a popup
  observeEvent(input$mymap_shape_mouseover$id, {
    pointId <- input$mymap_shape_mouseover$id
    lat = uu[uu$row_num == pointId, Latitude]
    lng = uu[uu$row_num == pointId, Longitude]
    offset = isolate((input$mymap_bounds$north - input$mymap_bounds$south) / (23 + radius + (18 - input$mymap_zoom)^2 ))

    leafletProxy("mymap") %>% addPopups(lat = lat + offset, lng = lng, as.character(pointId))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```